# Microsoft Report Viewer Error on IIS Server

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, reportviewer

Hi guys I just want you to help me about the Microsoft Report Viewer Error on IIS Server. I have a freshly installed windows server, enable IIS and and test the application I develop on Visual Studio. The thing is that on my pc its working fine but when I deploy it on the IIS Server. I encountered this error

[image: Error]

which drives me crazy. Is it I need to to installed report viewer on IIS Server which I already did and still encounter the same error. Please help me with this, thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is self explanatory. Can you check the log file in the report server?

Comment: Looks like the DLL is missing from the assembly?